# Best way to get list of nodes inside of Puppet template

Tags: puppet

What is the recommended way of getting a list of all the nodes from within a Puppet template?

Let's say I have a load balancer running Nginx. Inside of the template, I want to generate a list of backend servers. For the sake of simplicity, let's say these app-servers have a hostname that matches 'appserver*'.

Currently, I define an array inside site.pp with each app-server, and use that as follows:

```
upstream www.foobar.com {
  <% appservers.each do |val| -%>
  server <%= val %>:80;
  <% end -%>
}
```

I'd like to do away with that manually defined array, and instead query Puppet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one recommended way. It depends on your setup I guess.

There are several ways to achieve this. You can use [exported resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_exported.html) and query [puppetDB](https://github.com/dalen/puppet-puppetdbquery).

The method I prefer, because I'm already using Foreman, is to use foremans [parser function](https://github.com/ohadlevy/puppet-foreman/blob/master/foreman/lib/puppet/parser/functions/foreman.rb) to get the nodes list from foreman.

So in your manifest, you can do something like:

`$appservers = foreman("hosts", 'hostgroup = appservers')`

Assuming your app-servers are in Foremans hostgroup calles 'appservers'.
[Here](http://blog.theforeman.org/2012/01/getting-foreman-search-results-into.html) is a blog post that explains it.

Another way, would be to store your 'appserver' list in a text file, or database, then write your own function to retrieve the list. As you can see, writing a parser function is easy.

Another way is to use [Hiera](https://puppetlabs.com/blog/first-look-installing-and-using-hiera/).

Comment: Assuming one wouldn't want to use Foreman, 'Exported Resources' appears to be the way to go as far as I can tell. Will need some research, but it's a good first step. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. I lean towards Hiera these days, but YMMV. Also exported resources were a little slow, for large number of hosts. This has  probably changed, but if you have many hosts (few hundred+) then you may want to investigate.